# How to select/unselect rows in table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have event `ng-click()` over each row in table. How to add class `new` if I click over a table row and remove class after double click? I tried to create an array that contents `true`/`false` values for each key:

#### View

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
     <div ng-click="select(i)"></div>
</div>
```

#### Script

```
$scope.select = function(obj){
    $scope.selected[obj.id].show = true;
}

$scope.delete = function(obj){
    $scope.selected[obj.id].show = false;
}
```

Comment: what json actually list contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your object when clicking on it.

Try the snippet below and click on a line. It will add the property `selected` to the object.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    "name": "A",
    "description": "foo"
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "description": "fooo"
  }];
  $scope.select = function(i) {
    if (i.selected === undefined)
      i.selected = false;
    i.selected = !i.selected;
  }
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="i in list">
    <div ng-click="select(i)" ng-class="{'new': i.selected}">
      {{i.name}} - {{i.description}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Darama Could you please elaborate ? The code provided is working fine